# How to use firefox sync?

Tags: firefox

I'd like to have all firefox installations I use synced. The "starting point" should be a specific firefox installation, from now called "Firefox A". Means: First, every firefox installation is like this installation "A", then everything I change at one installation is applied to all the others.

Now and then I'm on another PC which is mine then for some weeks, there I'd like to log in - have all my Bookmarks, Add-Ons etc and everything I change from there should be applied to all the other installations. After some weeks I'd like to log-out again and everything should be like before.

I never have to of this devices together!

This should be able to do with firefox sync, shouldn't it? But I don't get it.

I red all supertartikels on the official firefox website.

So what did I try?

From Firefox Installation "A" I made a sync account, from another I connected to sync. What happened. Suddenly I have a hodgepodge from bookmarks that were there before and from the bookmarks from the other installation. My Add-Ons from the Installation "A" were there. My Tabs weren't synced. From then nothing synced anymore. no matter if I changed my bookmarks or Tabs on the one or the other installation - nothing synced.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an option that allows you to overwrite everything on one machine. When you add a new device, there should be an option on it that will overwrite all local content with the stuff that's stored on the server.

I don't think your tabs will sync. Also, it won't be an instant process. Don't expect new bookmarks to show up on another PC the instant you add them to the first one. You will get them after a while however.

Comment: I tried it, but it did'nt work (not option but the whole synchronisation)

Comment: Does nothing synchronize at all, even after waiting a while, restarting firefox, and so on? In that case you should try disconnecting one computer from sync and then adding it again. That might make a difference.

Comment: I tried this also, but I gave it up, firefox sync is too complicated for me ;-)

Comment: That's too bad. If you feel like taking another stab at it, typing "about:sync-log" into the address bar should display the log directory. You should see something like "1349086607927 Sync.Engine.Bookmarks DEBUG Engine initialized" in the files. The leftmost number is a Unix timestamp that you can convert with a tool like this one: http://www.epochconverter.com/